# Serializing values to JSON array with pipes

Tags: json, haskell, aeson, haskell-pipes

I'd like to serialize incoming values to JSON. Every value has a `toJSON` instance. The end result should be a list. The current code is the following:

```hs
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P

-- assume a source of elements
main :: IO ()
main = runEffect $ source >-> P.map encode >-> P.stdoutLn
```

The problem is that in this way every line contains a valid JSON object, but I want the whole result to be parseable. I'd like that before the first object a `[` character is outputted, then every element followed by a comma, and finally another `]`. How can I do this with pipes?

Current output:

```
$ prog
{"key": "value"}
{"key": "value"}
```

Desired output:

```
$ prog
[{"key": "value"},
{"key": "value"}]
```

I found pipes-aeson but I don't understand how should I use the functions it provides.

**EDIT**: I modified ErikR's answer to get a `Consumer`, but it does not output the closing bracket:

```
jsonExporter :: Consumer (FilePath, AnalysisResult) IO ()
jsonExporter = do
    lift $ putStr "["
    P.map encode >-> insertCommas
    lift $ putStr "]"
```

I cannot understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pipe segment:

```
for cat $ \x -> lift $ do { putStr ", "; putStrLn x }
```

will emit a comma before each element in the pipe.

To give the first element special treatment, we just unroll the loop once:

```
insertCommas = do
  x1 <- await
  lift $ putStrLn x1      -- print first element w/o a comma
  for cat $ \x -> lift $ do { putStr ", "; putStrLn x }
```

Now you can write your streaming JSON pipeline as:

```
putStr "["
runEffect $ source >-> P.map encode >-> insertCommas
putStrLn "]"
```

Comment: Great! I'm still getting used to `lift` and sometimes I find it hard to use it correctly.

Comment: Since Aeson's `encode` returns a ByteString I think I can use the [`intersperse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-bytestring-2.1.1/docs/Pipes-ByteString.html#v:intersperse) function from the pipes-group package somehow? Instead of `insertCommas` I mean.

Comment: You can try it, but I think that intersperses a character between every pair of characters in the Bytestring.

Comment: I needed a `Consumer`, so I modified your code (I put it in the question). But I cannot understand why the closing `]` is never outputted.

Comment: This should really be a new question. As a pipe segment `insertCommas` never returns, so that's why I print the brackets outside of the runEffect.

Comment: You are right, the issue is a bit more involved. I asked it in the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33464543/forking-the-streaming-flow-in-haskell-pipes

Thank you for your patience and help.